# Google Maps, scraping address

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'm using cheerio to scrape the next html.

```
<div class="google-map-wrap " style="padding-bottom:50px;">
<div class="google-map"></div><style>.google-map{width: 100%; height: 420px;} 
.google-map img {max-width:none !important;}</style><script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".google-map").gmap3({marker:{address: "Periferico Sur 2020"},map:{options:{zoom: 14,}}});});
```

I tried the following options and they haven't worked.

Expected = "Periferico Sur 2020"

```
$('div.google-map-wrap div.google-map').text()

$('div.google-map-wrap div.google-map').html()

$('div.google-map-wrap div.google-map').css()
```

But not working the result should be the address.

Comment: do you want to get the address in the <script></script> tag?

Comment: It should return the address

Comment: result "Periferico Sur 2020"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the information that would be needed by someone who's never seen your code before, as clearly as possible.

Comment: Why would querying the CSS for a `div` element ever give you the text "Periferico Sur 2020"? Why would getting the HTML for a map element give you a single string? Also, ["Cheerio is not a web browser"](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#cheerio-is-not-a-web-browser), so if you're expecting it to run the actual Google Maps code, you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, with your explanation you gave me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented before, cheerio won't be able to do it. But request already has the html so we can use it to find the string with indexOf(). Example:

.html

```
<div class="google-map-wrap " style="padding-bottom:50px;">
<div class="google-map"></div><style>.google-map{width: 100%; height: 420px;} 
.google-map img {max-width:none !important;}</style>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".google-map").gmap3({marker:{address: "Periferico Sur 2020"},map:{options:{zoom: 14,}}});});
```

.js

```
var readAddress = function(html){
 var idx1 = html.indexOf('{marker:{address: "');
 var idx2 = idx1 + '{marker:{address: "'.length;
 var idx3 = html.indexOf('"', idx2);

address = html.substring(idx2, idx3);
}

request(url, (err, res, data) => {
    readAddress(data);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you're trying to find an address from the maps, but here are a few options for solving your problem. The first is with the use of a [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). [Check the full code in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-Maps-Address-NodeJS-SerpApi#index.js)

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const URL = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/Boeing/@47.6121987,-122.6126448,11z/";

async function getPlaceAddress() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(URL);
  await page.waitForSelector(".hfpxzc");
  await page.click(".hfpxzc");
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

  const address = await page.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelector(".Io6YTe ").textContent;
  });

  await browser.close();
  console.log("Address: ", address);
}

getPlaceAddress();
```

Output:

```
Address:  7755 E Marginal Way S, Seattle, WA 98108
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Google Maps Local Results API](https://serpapi.com/maps-local-results) from SerpApi.

The difference is that all that needs to be done is to iterate over a structured JSON instead of coding everything from scratch.

Example code to integrate:

```js
const SerpApi = require("google-search-results-nodejs");
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY);         //your API key from serpapi.com

const query = "Boeing";                                                       // what we want to search

const params = {
  engine: "google_maps",                                                      // search engine
  type: "search",                                                             // Parameter defines the type of search you want to make
  google_domain: "google.com",                                                // Parameter defines the Google domain to use
  q: query,                                                                   // search query
  hl: "en",                                                                   // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
  ll: "@47.6121987,-122.6126448,11z",                                         // Parameter defines GPS coordinates of location where you want your query to be applied
};

const getPlaceAddress = function ({ local_results }) {
  console.log("Address: ", local_results[0].address);
};

const getJson = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    search.json(params, resolve);
  });
};

getJson().then(getPlaceAddress);
```

Output:

```
Address:  7755 E Marginal Way S, Seattle, WA 98108
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi